# Laravel :values placeholder not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I've created a custom validator for extensions:

```
Validator::extend('extension', function ($attribute, $file, $extensions, $validator) {
    $ext = strtolower(@$file->getClientOriginalExtension());

    return in_array($ext, $extensions);
});
```

And the custom message:

```
'extension' => 'The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.',
```

It doesn't seem to replace the `:values` part.

I've tried using the custom replace also without luck:

```
Validator::replacer('wtf', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
    return 'show me something!!!!!';
});
```

But this doesn't do anything either.

What's missing?

Comment: Have you tested using this message: `The :attribute must be a file of type :values.`?

Comment: Yes, it's not working. Plus I just copied it directly from the `mimes` type validation `'mimes' => 'The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.',`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel doesn't translate `values` placeholder by default. You did the right thing by using `replacer` ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules)). But looks like you made some mistakes.

A ServiceProvider code:

```
// in boot method define validator
Validator::extend('extension', function ($attribute, $file, $extensions, $validator) {
    $ext = strtolower(@$file->getClientOriginalExtension());

    return in_array($ext, $extensions);
});
// then - replacer with the same name
Validator::replacer('extension', 
    function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $extensions) {
        return str_replace([':values'], [join(", ", $extensions)], $message);
});
```

In controller:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'file' => 'required|extension:jpg,jpeg',
]);
```

In language file:

```
'extension' => 'The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.',
```